# Add a one to many edge - Tinkerpop (3.0.1)

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, titan, gremlin, tinkerpop3, gremlin-server

How can I add an edge from one vertex to many vertices in one call? I know I can call the usual addEdge with a single vertex but I'd like to avoid having to call gremlin server for each edge I need to add as there may be a quite a few.

This works in version 3.2.3 but the V method is not available in version 3.0.1 so looking to replicate it another way.

```
// Get vertices I want to add edge to
g.V().has("id",within(["2","3","4"])).as("toV").

// Now get the vertex I want to add edge from
V("1").as("fromV").

// And add an edge between them
addE("likes").from("fromV").to("toV")
```

Comment: Which version of TinkerPop do you use? Your last query should be fine using v3.2.x.

Comment: I'm stuck on 3.0.1-incubating for now due to the dynamodb storage backend.

Comment: Answer updated to reflect this.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the docs from TinkerPop 3.0.1 on the [addEdge step](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.0.1-incubating/#addedge-step), and you can find an example there for the syntax that you can use in Titan 1.0. You can test this out in the Gremlin Console.

```
graph = TitanFactory.open('inmemory'); g = graph.traversal()
g.addV('name', '1').addV('name', '2').addV('name', '3').addV('name', '4')
g.withSideEffect('a', g.V().has('name', within('2', '3', '4')).toList()).
    V().has('name', '1').addOutE('likes', 'a')
```